# Is "Jesus" based on the Egyptian sun god Horus?

Tags: religion, jesus-christ, egypt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Claimed similarities between Jesus Christ and Horus and other Gods](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1678/claimed-similarities-between-jesus-christ-and-horus-and-other-gods)

I've seen and read a lot of information about this. Take this [article](http://www.abovetopsecret.com/forum/thread290806/pg1) for example, and this [video](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=8&sqi=2&ved=0CHAQtwIwBw&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-17BNU7L6g&ei=0eaFTpzZKMT30gHL1LT-Dw&usg=AFQjCNENjxNwyI-X8GGJPFgp7FwHB2PS1A).

I believe the video excerpt is from Zeitgeist (the movie). The Wikipedia article on the movie suggests that Part I (the religious part) is only "half" true:

> Skeptic magazine's Tim Callahan criticizing the first part of the film
>   (on the origins of Christianity) wrote that "some of what it asserts
>   is true. Unfortunately, this material is liberally — and sloppily —
>   mixed with material that is only partially true and much that is
>   plainly and simply bogus. […] Zeitgeist is The Da Vinci Code on
>   steroids."[26] Acharya S (aka D.M. Murdock), a source and last-minute
>   consultant on the official version of the film, responded to
>   Callahan's critique in an article on her publishing company's website.
>   She writes that "it is a curious fact that writers who toss around the
>   words 'sloppy', 'garbled' and 'nonsense' are often guilty of these
>   very things themselves" and that Callahan's "declaration that much of
>   the material in ZG is 'plainly and simply bogus' is false."[27]
>   Callahan responded to Acharya's rebuttal with a counter-rebuttal
>   published in his website's forum.

How "true" is this?

Comment: The claim here is unclear. Would this be better asked on Christianity.SE?

Comment: I don't think so, this is about the skepticism that Jesus Christ is based on the Sun God Horus of the Egyptian faith.

Comment: Pretty similar to: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1678/claimed-similarities-between-jesus-christ-and-horus-and-other-gods

Comment: I suspect that this will be impossible to answer.  Many religions/philosophies have common characteristics that are not the result of copying.  Themes such as familial/parental ties and (self) sacrifice are common in a wide range of otherwise unrelated religions.  It would be difficult to pick out all the bits and pieces of Christianity and not find most of those same bits and pieces (in slightly different hues) in other contemporary religions, including Mithraism.  Also see [this Wikipedia article comparing Jesus and Horus.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_Christ_in_comparative_mythology)